# Three monitors on Radeon 6870

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [3 Monitors on Sapphire Radeon HD 6870](https://superuser.com/questions/394918/3-monitors-on-sapphire-radeon-hd-6870)

I have an [Asus 
Radeon 6870](http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/EAH68702DI2S1GD5/) with four places to connect a monitor.

[image]

I am using three 1920x1080 monitors, connected to the following ports:

```
   Card                         Monitor
   DVI    -------------------->    DVI
   HDMI   -------------------->    HDMI
Mini DP   ----> Convertor ---->    DVI
```

This is the convertor I use:  [Mini DisplayPort to DVI converter](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00310K9VQ/ref=oh_details_o00_s00_i00h)

[image]

My card detects all three monitors, but when I go to extend the desktop onto the third monitor, this error comes up and I cannot get all three to work at the same time.

"To extend the desktop, a desktop or display must be disabled." with "Continue" and "Cancel" as options.

I tried the left DVI, the HDMI and I have tried both Mini DPs with the adapter.

I have looked at the other thread on this site in order to solve this problem, still no working solution.

Comment: I added the extra information gained from this last set of forth and back comments to the post. Can you check if I got it right? After you verified it can you delete the remaining comments to keep the post clean?

Comment: I think the make is "Powercolour", Just checked inside the case to verify. It does look an awful lot like the asus one! http://img.directcanada.com/images/POWERCOLOR/AX6870_1GBD5-2DH/AX6870_1GBD5-2DH_1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Most modern graphics cards, including this one based on the error, only support 2 display outputs at a time.  Even though it detects the third monitor, it will be unable to use it without disabling one of the ports in use.

There are graphics cards that support more than 2 displays out, but they are more specialized cards.

Comment: I have seen other people using the same card in order to get a three monitor display, though!

Comment: are you *positive* that the radeon was driving all 3 monitors?  Are you sure another video card was not driving the 3rd?

Comment: definitely sure!

Comment: @keltari Yes, the whole AMD HD 5xxx/6xxx/7xxx series is designed to drive at least up to 3 displays at the same time. And a few even up to 6. The reference cards though come with 4 connectors (2xDVI, 1x HDMI, 1x DP) and to use 3 displays at least one of them needs to use the DP port.

Comment: did some googling, and found an answer... here on superuser, so Im voting to close with a link to the other answer.

Comment: As stated above, this other page doesn't work.